# Vue.js Sorting using a underscore sortBy

Tags: sorting, underscore.js, vue-component, vuejs2

Trying to implement a sortBy method on a Vue component. Here's what I have so far.

```
var studentTableComp =  {
    template: '#studentTable',
    data: function () {
        return {
            students: data,
            show: true,
            columns: [
                'id',
                'candidateType',
                'complete'
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sortBy: function (sortKey, e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            _.sortBy(this.students.students, sortKey);
        }
    },
}
```

And I can see that the sortBy function is being hit, and that the parameters sortKey are being sent correctly from the template, but the problem seems to be with the `_.sortBy` function doesn't have any effect on the `this.students.students` array.

Any ideas why it doesn't working.
I've tried the `_.sortBy` method using Underscores example array, and it works fine, but I think something happens to the array when it is added to the data on the Vue component that might be preventing this function from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I see `_.sortBy` working, see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/jot8wvyf/).

Here is the code:

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return {
        students: [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}]
      };
    },
    methods: {
      sorted: function() {
        return _.sortBy(this.students, 'name');
      }
    }
})
```

Add more code from your repo, if you see still this is not resolved.

Comment: Thanks - but it looks like the above is the exact same code that I'm using with one exception.  I have sorting data that is on a Vue Component rather than the Vue object itself.  I had thought it might be something to do with the data array - but I've given the component the array you have above and checked the array before and after the _.sortBy function but there is no change to the array